# Auto refresh in excel is not functioning

Tags: excel

How do I set auto refresh to an excel sheet at one minutes interval, which contains data from external web page(rss).

I followed [**the steps described in this link**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Refresh-external-data-in-Excel-Services-a7624837-cf74-4cf6-b269-6418458151f6).

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in VBA.  In your "ThisWorkbook" module, create a `Workbook_Open` event that looks something like this:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
  Module1.RefreshEveryMinute
End Sub
```

Then, in your `Module1` module/class, the code that actually does the refresh would look something like this:

```
Public Sub RefreshEveryMinute()

  ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

  nextRunTime = Now + TimeValue("00:01:00")
  Application.OnTime nextRunTime, "RefreshAllData"
End Sub
```